# Disable "Share Wishlist" and "email to friend"?

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to disable Share Wishlist with friend feature, as well as, another product sharing feature: "Email to Friend".

Is there a way to disable any of these two in the Admin Panel ? 
If not, what is the other most efficient way of disabling these mailing feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes way.

1. Wishlist share.

   In your `app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\layout\local.xml` add these lines:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    ....<!-- might be some stuff already there -->
    <layout> 
     <wishlist_index_index translate="label">
      <reference name="customer.wishlist.buttons">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>customer.wishlist.button.share</name></action>
      </reference>   
     </wishlist_index_index>
   </layout>
   ```
2. Send to a friend.

   In your `app/etc/local.xml` add these lines:

   ```
   <config>
   .....<!-- might be some stuff already there -->
     <default>
      <sendfriend>
       <email>
           <enabled>0</enabled>
       </email>
      </sendfriend>
     </default>
   </config>
   ```

After steps 1 and 2 clear magento cache and you are all set.

Comment: Gerasimov - Highly appreciate your response!

Comment: very welcome sir!

Answer (score 0):

Code edits are not needed to disable the wishlist. There's a setting for it. Open the Magento Admin and go to:

`System > Configuration > Customer > Wishlist > General options`

Here, you have the option to disable the wishlist, by setting `enabled` to 'no'.  Clear cache and you're done!

[image: wishlist enabled configuration screenshot]

Comment: OP didn't want to disable the wishlist in it's entirety. They wanted to disable the share wishlist functionality, while still maintaining the ability to add products to your wishlist. Your proposed solution does not solve this problem.